# How to find files with names having a long string after the first dot

Tags: find, regular-expression

My Samsung Galaxy S doesn't like files where the name contains a long string after the first dot. I guess some part of the software has a too short buffer for the file extension. How can I find all files on my Micro-SD-Card mounted at /media/sd where the filename has more than five characters after the first dot?

Reading the find manpage, I thought

`find . -regex '.*\..\{5,\}'`

would work, but it doesn't give any hits, so I somehow don't get my regular expression right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the default type of regex's used by find is emacs-style. Find's [documentation for emacs style regexes](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#emacs-regular-expression-syntax) doesn't include the `\{n,\}` construction--leading me to believe that it isn't supported in find's implemenation of emacs-style regular expressions. The [emacs-wiki lists this as valid](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression#toc1), however it is possible that this wasn't always the case.

I found that your regex produced output if you do this:

```
$ find . -regextype posix-basic -regex '.*\..\{5,\}'
```

Comment: Yes, this indeed works. As an Emacs user who knows the \{\} syntax, I didn't bother to look up finds emacs regex syntax as I assumed it would be the same. Shame on me for being so full of trust for GNU :-)

Answer (score 2):

Braces are not always included in basic regexp implementations. I don't know if you have GNU find or Busybox find; Busybox may not have all the features of GNU find.

A portable way to search for files with a long extension is `find . -name '*.?????*'`.

Note that your regexp would match most files under a directory whose name contains a dot.